# No me cargan los datos del custom type

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Buenos dias, nose porque no me cargan los datos del custom type y se me pone en blanco la pagina de wordpress, este es el codigo:

```html
<div class="contenido-portada">
<?php $argumentos = array(
      'post-type'=>'slider'
      'category_name' => 'sliderhome',
      'post_per_page'=> 5,
      'orderby'=> 'date',
      'order'=>'ASC'); ?>
    <?php $slider = new WP_Query($argumentos); 
    while($slider->have_posts()): $slider->the_post();
    ?>
      <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>

      <div class="slider" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $url; ?>); background-size: cover;">
        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        <h1><?php the_content(); ?></h1>
        <a href="<?php the_field('link_de_slider') ?>">More</a>
        </div>
    
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema de sintaxis esta en el array $argumentos en el 'post-type', debes de cambiarlo por 'post_type' y agregarle la coma al finalizar el valor 'slider' en la misma linea.

Debería quedar así:

```
<?php $argumentos = array(
      'post_type'=>'slider',
      'category_name' => 'sliderhome',
      'post_per_page'=> 5,
      'orderby'=> 'date',
      'order'=>'ASC'); ?>
```

Te recomiendo que cuando estés desarrollando con Wordpress habilites el modo de depuración en el archivo wp-config.php modifica la siguiente línea a true:

```
define(‘WP_DEBUG’, true);
```

Intentalo y me cuentas.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, Alejandro. Para futuras preguntas o respuestas, puedes revisar aquí [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: Como es eso del modo de depuracion?

Comment: Hola @LuisMoralesPonce, para conocer más del tema te invito que mires este link. https://codex.wordpress.org/es:Depurar_en_WordPress

Answer (score 0):

Cambia

```
'post-type'=>'slider'
```

Por

```
'post_type'=>'slider',
```

es con guion bajo y te falta la coma al final, ese puede ser el problema